# php - how to get xml tag by id

Tags: php, xml

I have XML in this format

```
<hotels>
    <hotel>
        <id>285</id>
        <name>Alexander</name>
        <price>250 USD</price>
    </hotel>

    <hotel>
        <id>678</id>
        <name>Hilton</name>
        <price>480 USD</price>
    </hotel>                
</hotels>
```

How do i get the name of hotel where id is 678 by using PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @Domso - is the hotel tag was like this: `<hotel id='285'>....</hotel>` , would it was easier to get the NAME tag or do i still had to use FOREACH loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to parse xml string. Then loop through `hotel` tag and check content of `id`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel)
    $hotel->id == "678" ? @$name = (string)$hotel->name : '';
echo $name;
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/iAtG3)

---

Also you can use [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) if you don't want to use `foreach`

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($str);
$name = (new DOMXpath($doc))->query("//hotel[id[text()='678']]/name")[0]->nodeValue;
// Hilton
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/UOgFr)

Comment: Thank. Do i have to use FOREACH loop and run on all the sections? is there any function that find section according some value?

Comment: @Roi There is `DOMXpath` that i added to answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for :

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<hotels>
    <hotel>
        <id>285</id>
        <name>Alexander</name>
        <price>250 USD</price>
    </hotel>

    <hotel>
        <id>678</id>
        <name>Hilton</name>
        <price>480 USD</price>
    </hotel>                
</hotels>
XML;

$hotel = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$list = $hotel->hotel;
$count = count($list);
while($count > 0){
    $count--;
    $id = $hotel->hotel[$count]->id;
    if($id == 678){
        $name = $hotel->hotel[$count]->name;
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank. Do i have to use WHILE loop and run on all the sections? is there any function that find section according some value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleXML and XPath to find the hotel without using loops..

```
$data ='<hotels>
    <hotel>
        <id>285</id>
        <name>Alexander</name>
        <price>250 USD</price>
    </hotel>

    <hotel>
        <id>678</id>
        <name>Hilton</name>
        <price>480 USD</price>
    </hotel>
</hotels>';

$hotel = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$hotel678 = $hotel->xpath("//hotel[id='678']");
echo $hotel678[0]->name;
```